# WPF Print with FlowDocument template

Tags: c#, wpf, printing, report, flowdocument

I´m trying to make some reports on a WPF application but I´m a really beginner on the language.
So far I saw some examples on using FlowDocument + PrinDialog to print.
Mostly, when loading data from a database, the examples show how to dynamically create the FlowDocument from codebehind, like:

```
FlowDocument flowDoc = new FlowDocument();
Paragraph paraHeader = new Paragraph();
paraHeader.FontSize = 12;
paraHeader.Foreground = headerBrsh;
paraHeader.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
paraHeader.Inlines.Add(new Run(someDataFromDB));
flowDoc.Blocks.Add(paraHeader);
...
```

And so on, adding as many items as I need.

What I want to know is if there's anyway to create a FlowDocument XAML template with all the elements and formating and bind the elements text/values to a DataSource that I'll bind when loading the FlowDocument.

Example:

```
//SomeXAMLTemplate
<FlowDocument>
   <Paragraph FontSize="18" FontWeight="Bold" Background="Black" Foreground="White">
      <Run Text="{Binding SomeProperty}"/>  
   </Paragraph>
</FlowDocument>
```

And then load it in code like this:

```
FlowDocument flowDoc = ReadFromXAMLAsFlowDocument(someXAMLFile);
flowDoc.DataContext = myListObject;
```

I didn't find how to make de XAML properly to get the bindings working.

Could anyone point me the directions or show a working example?